# Make a flip puzzle with 2 backgrounds images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for help to make a flip puzzle with 2 background images.

Something similar as this example I found on another post from this community:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/LdR29/)

but, instead of all all the `?` symbols I want to show another image, and maybe randomize some cells so that some start as the `front face (? symbols cells)` and other as the back face (showing part of the background image).

And if there is a way to validate that if one of both images (front or back) is completed, show it as a modal window. So far I've managed to flip an image and show another background. So I need help doing the grids and cells so I can flip the cards. Here's my markup:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Styles/flipStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/mainControl.js"></script>

<title>Flipping Ad</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flip-container" id="myContainer">
        <div class="flipper canvas">
            <div class="front" onclick="app.controller.flip()">
                <!-- front content -->
            </div>
            <div class="back" onclick="app.controller.flip()">
                <!-- back content -->
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container.hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    background-image:url('../Images/300x300.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
    /* for firefox 31 */
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    background:url('../Images/300x300_2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

javaScript (using underscore):

```
(function (app){
    'use strict';

    app.controller={};
    _.extend(app.controller,{
        toggle_flip: toggle_flip,
        flip: flip,
    });
function toggle_flip(){

        document.querySelector("#myCard").classList.toggle("flip")
    }
    function voltear(){
        document.querySelector('#myContainer').classList.toggle('hover');
    }
})(window.app = window.app || {});
```

All together, works like this example I found, using the toggle one.

[Working Example](https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php)

Comment: @thickguru  Thanks for the edit on my post and make it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to provide two images, so i moved the images as `data-` attributes to the DOM (*instead of the CSS*).

```
<div class='canvas' data-background="http://placekitten.com/500/300" data-foreground="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300">
</div>
```

You also need to change the script to not add the `?` in the `.back` so that part becomes

```
var cell = $("<div class='cell flipped'><div class='back'></div><div class='front'></div></div>")
```

You  then need to repeat the part that adds the background and positions it on the `.front` to also do it for the `.back`.

```
    cell.find('.back')
        .css('background','url('+foregroundImage+')')
        .css('background-position', -(j * colWidth) + 'px ' + -(i * rowHeight) + 'px');
```

To randomize some of the cells use `Math.random()` to decide if you will flip each cell

```
if (Math.random() >= 0.5) cell.toggleClass('flipped');
```

And finally every time you flip a cell, check if the number of flipped elements is 0 (*front image complete*) or `col*row` (*back image complete*)

```
      var flipped = canvas.find('.flipped').length;
      if ((flipped == col*row) || !flipped){
        alert('Full Image');
      }
```

The part that show the image in modal i leave to you.

Updated demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/LdR29/35/